# .net web api does not return in json format

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

i have controller in web api that called "vote", this is a post request that takes some parameters from the body and it should return the id of the voter if it is success, or return "already voted" if he has voted before. for the second scenario, i get right. but when the user votes successfully i get this error

```
   {
"message": "An error has occurred.",
"exceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
"exceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"stackTrace": null,
"innerException": {
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "Error while copying content to a stream.",
    "exceptionType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()",
    "innerException": {
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "exceptionMessage": "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.",
        "exceptionType": "System.ObjectDisposedException",
        "stackTrace": "   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ReleaseConnection()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.Finally()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
    }
}
}
```

this is my webapi config

```
Public Class CustomJsonFormatter
    Inherits JsonMediaTypeFormatter

    Public Sub New()
        Me.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(New System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"))
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub SetDefaultContentHeaders(ByVal type As Type, ByVal headers As HttpContentHeaders, ByVal mediaType As MediaTypeHeaderValue)
        MyBase.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType)
        headers.ContentType = New MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
    End Sub
End Class

Module WebApiConfig

    Sub Register(ByVal config As HttpConfiguration)
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication()
        config.Filters.Add(New HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType))
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()



        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="DefaultApi", routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", defaults:=New With {Key .id = RouteParameter.[Optional]})

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter)
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = New Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    End Sub
End Module

End Namespace
```

and this is the controller

```
 Namespace Controllers
Public Class VoteController
    Inherits ApiController






    Function Post(<FromBody> ByVal user As Voting) As HttpResponseMessage

        Try
            Using entities As ElectionsEntities = New ElectionsEntities()
                Dim entity = entities.Votings.FirstOrDefault(Function(e) e.Elector_FK_ID = user.Elector_FK_ID)
                If entity Is Nothing Then
                    Dim message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, entities.SP_Voting_Insert(user.Elector_FK_ID, user.City_FK_ID, user.Voting_Center_FK_ID, user.class_FK_ID))
                    message.Headers.Location = New Uri(Request.RequestUri, user.Elector_FK_ID.ToString())
                    Return message
                Else
                    Dim message = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "هذا الشخص قام بالتصويت")
                    Return message
                End If
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            Return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, e)
        End Try
    End Function

End Class
 End Namespace
```

and here is the SP for inserting

```
 @Elector_FK_ID bigint,
@City_FK_ID bigint,
@Voting_Center_FK_ID bigint,
@class_FK_ID as bigint
 AS
 BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;


insert into [Elections].[dbo].[Voting]
(
    [Elector_FK_ID],[VoteDate],[City_FK_ID],[Voting_Center_FK_ID],[class_FK_ID]
)
values
(
    @Elector_FK_ID,getdate(),@City_FK_ID,@Voting_Center_FK_ID,@class_FK_ID
)
select @@IDENTITY
```

any help would be appreciated, 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The inner exception looks like it's related to Entity Framework. Often the "context has been disposed..." errors in EF relate to [deferred execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution). Are you sure that everything within your USING scope is being executed immediately? I'm looking at the entities.SP_Voting_Insert() method in particular. I can only infer what it does, but it's possible that you need to ensure that it executes immediately, rather than after the object context is disposed.

(Would have posted as a comment, but alas... I don't have the privilege yet.)

Comment: the SP working fine, by the way it adds the user to database, but it prompts that error, but i need to return the response without any error

Comment: Hmm... does the user creation method (SP_Voting_Insert) contain code that disposes the object context by any chance?

Comment: i updated the question, i added the SP im using, take a look at it

Comment: Perhaps it's the SELECT @@IDENTITY query that isn't being executed until after the object context is disposed. 

Are you able to debug with breakpoints? I would try storing the result of the SP_Voting_Insert() in a variable and inspecting that, or you could just try calling SP_Voting_Insert().ToString() or a similar method to force execution. 

Sorry for the vague suggestions -- I have experience with EF, but not VB.NET.